# bash - call of jq generates syntax errors and INVALID_CHARACTER messages

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, error-handling, jq

I am trying to understand why my script is choking when jq is called.

Here is the code. I called jq in three different ways and only the first option below works.

```
#define vars
jq_filter_filename_start="jq_filter_start.txt"
jq_filter_filename_end="jq_filter_end.txt"
check_config_list="CronJobName CronJobResult"
dc1="test.json"
jq_filter_start=$(<"$jq_filter_filename_start")
jq_filter_end=$(<"$jq_filter_filename_end")

# now Filter resulting json for missing properties
    
#case 1 - works without using bash vars
for i in $check_config_list; do
    jq -r --arg search_param "$i" '[.[] | select ( .Body.values)] | [.[] | select (all(.Body.values[]; .name != $search_param ) )] | .[].Header.Tenant' "$dc1"
    done

#case 2 - does not work when using vars and calling jq directly
for i in $check_config_list; do
    jq -r --arg search_param "$i" "$jq_filter_start" $search_param "$jq_filter_end" "$dc1"
    done

#case 3 - does not work when putting everything in an array
for i in $check_config_list; do
    jqcommand=(jq -r "$jq_filter_start" \""$i"\" "$jq_filter_end" "$dc1")
    ${jqcommand[@]}
    done
```

Here is the content of the `jq_filter_start.txt` and `jq_filter_end.txt` files - as you can guess - it is beginning and the end of jq filter:

```
'[.[] | select ( .Body.values)] | [.[] | select (all(.Body.values[]; .name !=
```

```
) )] | .[].Header.Tenant'
```

Could you please explain why I am getting the following output for both case 2 and case 3?

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
'[.[] | select ( .Body.values)] | [.[] | select (all(.Body.values[]; .name !=
jq: 1 compile error
```

I want to break down jq's filters and dynamically store them either at vars or at files and join them when necessary, as outlined above.

My jq filters starting to getting quite long and complex, one such example

```
[.[] | select ( .Body.extensions ) ] | [.[] | select ( (.Header.Tenant | test("^(?![a-z]{3}-[a-z][a-z1-9]{2}-p[1-9]$)[a-zA-Z0-9.,-]+$")) and (.Header.ProductType | test("Product")))] | .[].Header.Tenant
```

In the above example, I need to have an option to use vars in place of `.Body.extensions` and inside the `test()` conditions.

That's why I tried to use bash vars but seems I am missing something...

P.S. Example JSON below. The purpose of this script is to go thru the `CronJobName CronJobResult` and other parameters defined in the `check_config_list` to identify all these Tenants which are missing one or more such parameters.

```
[
    {
        "Header": {
            "Tenant": "mytenant"
        },
        "Body": {
            "values": [                
                {
                    "id": "aaaa0001-0a0a-0b0b-0c0c-07a3a4decaa6",
                    "name": "Currency"
                },
                {
                    "id": "aaaa0001-0a0a-0b0b-0c0c-9390805c3b09",
                    "name": "CronJobName"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Where is your JSON? Please update it

Comment: Why do you want to split the filter code in parts between the variable? Option 1 is the recommended approach

Comment: Better use a jq script in a file called `script.jq` and execute with it

Comment: I am trying not to have 300 char long lines when calling jq. That's why I tried to use vars....

In terms of calling jq filter in jq script - as outlined the parameters in the filter change  so I need to be able to construct the filter dynamically.

Comment: Why not use the —arg field when using the script. You can pass the argument in command line while involving the filter from script

Comment: Are you suggesting to dynamically construct the jq filter, write it in a filter file and then use that file while calling jq? 

@Inian - I will try your suggestion, but could you tell me what causes jq errors in case 2/3?

Comment: There is no dynamic construction of the script. Modify your script logic to expect the parameters from command line with `--arg` or `--argjson` (for JSON arguments)

Comment: You *can't* construct your JSON filter that way. Shell doesn't concatenate individual words like that and produce a resulting filter. Your first option is nice and clean, what is preventing you from using it is what I don't understand

Comment: Your first approach indeed is using bash vars, i.e. `"$i"` is imported from shell to the context of `jq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using files such as jq_filter_start.txt and jq_filter_end.txt to hold fragments of programs is almost certainly a bad idea (in general) for a wide variety of reasons, not least that it leads to the sort of errors displayed in the question. With that caveat in mind, let's consider one way to fix "Case 2".

Since the fix I have in mind is easier than explaining the problems you've run into, I'll focus on the former.

The fix can be accomplished by taking these three steps:

1. omit the leading `'` in jq_filter_start.txt;
2. omit the trailing `'` in jq_filter_end.txt;
3. change the invocation of jq to:

```
jq -r --arg search_param "$i" "$jq_filter_start \$search_param $jq_filter_end" "$dc1"
```

The point is that the jq program, when presented on the command line, has to be presented as a single "string".

But rather than dwelling further on these best-avoided paths, it might make sense to refocus attention on the actual problem that's prompting these explorations.

Comment: Thanks, @peak for providing the solution. 
My question -  I need to pass not just one, but 2-4 different parameters to jq - see the filter in the end of the question with regex and test. 
Do you suggest to use the above approach and all these params to jq? Or would it better as Inian suggested above to write everything in filter.jq and call it with -f?
Thanks

Comment: @Invisible999 - Please see separate answer/

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you use the -f command-line option is really a tangential matter here.

You could, for example, avoid fiddling with program fragments by performing the iteration within jq, e.g.:

```
jq -r '("CronJobName", "CronJobResult") as $search_param
  | [.[] | select( .Body.values)]
  | [.[] | select (all(.Body.values[]; .name != $search_param ) )]
  | .[].Header.Tenant' "$dc1"
```

or if you want the search parameter values to be provided externally:

```
jq -r --argjson search_params '["CronJobName", "CronJobResult"]' jq '
  $search_params[] as $search_param
  | [.[] | select ( .Body.values)]
  | [.[] | select (all(.Body.values[]; .name != $search_param ) )]
  | .[].Header.Tenant' "$dc1"
```

Please also note that if you wish to parameterize some jq code such as `.foo.bar`, you can either use a form such as .[$FOOSTRING][$BARSTRING] or getpath($ARRAY) so you can pass in the parameters programmatically.

You may also want to take advantage of jq's support for user-defined functions.